# Debug symbols for gstreamer

Tags: windows, debugging, gstreamer

I want to run gstreamer based program or standard gstreamer utility like `gst-play-1.0.exe` under `gdb` on Windows. <s>But [binaries for Windows](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/pkg/windows/1.8.1/) doesn't contain debug symbols.</s>

Where I can get debug version of gstreamer libraries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turned out, binaries **already** contain debug symbols. All is needed - use debugger correctly.

For example: to debug `gst-play-1.0.exe` you need to run:

> gdb.exe gst-play-1.0.exe

For now you can use any of gdb commands: get list of all functions by `info functions`, set breakpoints by `breakpoint name_of_function`, continue to run after breakpoint by `continue` and so on.